# Where do I find Devotional Sanskrit Stotra Sung in praise of Lord Kartikeya from?

Tags: stotra, kartikeya

There does not seem to be many Sanskrit stotras in praise of Lord Kartikeya. Being a member of the Shiva family I am wondering why aren't their many stotras in comparison to other gods?

Also, what are the stotras in praise of Lord Kartikeya? Are there any online audios of them? E.g. [this search](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Sanskrit%20Kartikeya&pbjreload=10) does not return many diverse valid results relative to other searchers. I am looking to collect as many Sanskrit Devotional Storas/Mantras of Lord Kartikeya in audio / video format.

Comment: Here is the list of the Kumar Kartikeya Stotram from various puranas like Shiva Purana ,Skanda Purana and composed by Rishi markandeya etc. - https://sanskritdocuments.org/sanskrit/subrahmanya/

Comment: This is too broad as well as off-topic. There can be any number of stotras on Subramanya and the answers turn out to be a list question without an end. since it is just helping in search in YouTube, it is more about knowing tips on searching YouTube and Google rather than knowing the subject (Hinduism). We are not a search engine to find stotras in a specific format.

Comment: @Pandya The OP specifically asked to help us locate the stotras in audio and video format on YouTube in title as well as body. Why did you remove YouTube and write anywhere?  Are we helping in googling videos also? If I remember correctly, such question was closed as off-topic in the past.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Well, yes, the proper question should be which are the stotras praising Kartikeya and answer can list out name of Stotras providing links to the text if possible. Another proper question may be finding particular stotra in audio format. So, the question needs to be fixed accordingly or can be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Pandya If you see the question asked by OP & not what we want, they are looking for help in finding as many stotras online/YT only. I don't think finding a particular stotra in audio format will be good too because it is finding a specific format. We only find a purana or a text online but not finding them in pdf, dejavu, word etc., and allow each and every question. I believe putting it on hold is not a big deal to avoid more and more incomplete list answers. You _can_ close it. Guidelines say we can close immediately if the question is improper. Closing will not stop editing.

Comment: Finding something in audio helps understand the correct pronunciation which is not possible in text-based format.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena You should [edit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/35838/edit) your question body according to what I [suggested](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35838/where-do-i-find-devotional-sanskrit-stotra-sung-in-praise-of-lord-kartikeya-from#comment113457_35838)

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena Your question now looks more confusing as the answer will be "anywhere on the internet". Please understand our site is not for locating Bhajans and stotras which is a function of a search engine. You intend to search as many as possible which makes question a list question and off-topic.

Comment: OK. Rolled back.

Answer (score 6):

You can find 25 stotras dedicated to Lord Karthikeya from [this page (Hindupedia.com)](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Stotra#Prayers_addressed_to_Lord_Subrhamanya). Few are in Sanskrit and few are in Tamil as well. Stotras are given transliterated English along with translations in English so that one realize what's being said in the stotras.

Names of few stotras are:

> Guha panchakam
>  Kanda Guru Kavacham of Santhananda Swamigal
>   (Tamil)
>  Kandhar Alankaram (Tamil)
>  Kandhar Anubhuthi
>   (Tamil)
>  Karthikeya Karavalamba stotram
>  Kumarashtakam
>   Pragya Vivardhana Karthikeya Stotram
>  Shadanana ashtakam
>   Shanmuga Kavacham (Tamil)
>  Shanmuga Shodasam

This resource will be useful for those who want to chant these stotras themselves.

Another similar site that I find useful is Bhartiweb.com. You need to go to the stotra section and do a search. I searched using terms like Karthikeya, Guha, Karthik, Shanmuga etc but none yielded any results. [Finally I searched for Subramanya and this time the search yielded eight results](http://www.bharatiweb.com/?s=subr).

Few stotras that you get from this site are: [Subramanya Trishati](http://www.bharatiweb.com/wp-content/uploads/Kumara-Subramanya-Trishati-Eng-v12.pdf), Subramanya stotra, [Subramanya Ashtottara Shatanamavali](http://www.bharatiweb.com/wp-content/uploads/Subramanya-Ashtottara-Shata-Namavali-Eng-v1.pdf) etc.

I did a search just now [on Youtube.com using the terms "Shubramanya Ashtakam"](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=subramanya%20ashtakam) and it yielded many useful results. You can check those. If we use different search terms more results might be obtained.

You can hear Shubramanya Sahsranama (1000 names) [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbQiseXBYPM) and Shubramanya 108 names from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OM4856cSslM).

Comment: +1 Can you help me locate the audio version of each stotra.

Comment: Finding the audios for each one of them will be difficult as you can understand. But when you know the names of the stotras you can yourself do youtube searches. Bound to get some useful results. I will also search myself (on youtube) later and update my answer. @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena